# How to export view to a vector image format in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I would like to export the exact view of agents layout (including their shapes and colors) into a vector image file format such as EPS, PDF, SVG,...

Is there any way to do that without vectorizing the generated PNG files with another application?

**EDIT 1:** 
I tried to write an extension as Seth recommended, but the generated image is as follows:
[Generated Image of the extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1nFd.png)

**EDIT 2:**
The problem was with the vector library I was using. Changing the library, the extension works like a charm!

Comment: This is not an answer, and for many purpose using the new extension would no doubt be better, but: On my system, choosing "Copy View" and then creating a new file from the clipboard in another program allows you to create *much* higher resolution output.  I discovered this after a publisher refused to publish figures I'd made with the standard `export-view` method.  (I used "create from clipboard" in MacOS's built-in Preview program).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question! Sadly no, this is not supported in stock NetLogo. It should be; I wish it were!

SVG would be an excellent choice of output format.

Someone with some knowledge of Java or Scala coding could write a NetLogo extension that does this, by recording the Java2D calls that the NetLogo renderer makes, using a library such as https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html.

Comment: Seth, I tried to write such an extension. However, I was only able to access the `BifferedImage` of the view. Is there any specific class trough which I can access the Java2D calls that NetLogo renderer makes?

Comment: `org.nlogo.render.Renderer` has an `exportView` method which takes a `Graphics2D` and an `api.ViewSettings`. I believe it's fine to instantiate a `Renderer` on the fly, as needed, by passing `workspace.world()` to the `Renderer` constructor.

Comment: Thanks @Seth. I instantiated a `Renderer` as you said and was able to have the view be drawn on a `Graphics2D`. However, the image that is drawn has a black background (while it must be white). Moreover, the turtles and links are not drawn completely. I am trying to temporarily upload the generated file in an edit beneath my post.

Comment: Dear Seth, the problem is resolved . Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool. Do you plan to publish the extension? Even if you don't officially publish it, it would be nice if you provided a link to the source code here, in case someone else wants to do something similar.

Comment: Sure! I will add it to the list of extensions in Github, ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

A new extension is built to export the view of model to a vector image file. The supported formats are EPS, PDF, and SVG. 
You can find the source and the built files here:

https://github.com/aesmaeili/vectorview

Comment: I was unable to  install it, could you provide steps?